# Message "CSRF token mismatch." While using Laravel sanctum token API. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am trying to build an API using Laravel sanctum token-based authentication. On postman, it works fine, and giving the desired output but for VueApp or any server running app, it is giving me an error response. Like below

`CSRF token mismatch.`

I Have two API Routes.

```
Route::post('/login',[App\http\controller\Api\MainController::class,'login']);

Route::post('/register',[App\http\controller\Api\MainController::class,'register']);
```

When hitting these endpoints with the postman, I am getting the desired output as the response, But When trying to the same with Vue/CLI application using Axios, getting the below response...

`CSRF token mismatch.`